# Confusion related to DFT in a paper

Tags: fourier-transform

I was reading a [paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/119050/PASTE-sigmod10.pdf) related to privacy where they perform fourier transformation of a time series data and retain few coefficients of the FFT. Then they apply some noise to these coefficients. These noisy coefficients are zero padded. Finally inverse DFT is applied to obtain the original data which is not exactly equal to the original since noise is added plus some of the coefficients are removed.

I wanted to start with something simple. I took number N=1:100. I applied DFT to these numbers and got the coefficients. I removed the last 50 coefficients and replaced them with zeros. Then I took the inverse DFT of it and tried to reconstruct the original signal of 1:100. However I got something like this

26.5000000000000 + 64.2447047766005i    25.5019732715717 + 32.4869793423559i    27.4940879728862 + 32.3616461087916i    26.5118007221575 + 21.9701324299717i    28.4803838832861 + 21.7214425428068i    27.5293273669910 + 15.7167080225067i    29.4591038528792 + 15.3485834698221i and so on

This is no where close to my original signal of 1,2,3, and so on.

What am I doing wrong?

I have attached the algorithm from the paper below. I am first trying with something simple. I am not adding the noise using LPA algorithm as said in the algorithm. I am just apply DFT, selecting first 50 coefficients padding them by zeros. Then I applied Inverse DFT to try to reconstruct the original signal

[image]

Comment: Posted 45 minutes earlier to [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/409319/15941) where it already has received an answer. I had suggested that the OP ask to have the question _migrated_ here. Instead, the OP has chosen to post a separate question (with more details).

Comment: @DilipSarwate. Why are you doing this?

Comment: The real question is "Why are _you_ behaving in an inappropriate manner?" You have wasted the time of several people on (at least) two different stackexchange sites.

Comment: Why are time wasted?

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it seems that what you are doing is the following:

- Take FFT of real input of size 100.
- Truncate coefficients 51 to 100 (using one-based indexing).
- Take IFFT.

Unless you are using FFT functions specifically designed for real input and output (such as `numpy.fft.rfft` and `numpy.fft.irfft` in numpy), this is incorrect because you are affecting the bins corresponding to negative frequencies, which should kept symmetric with the corresponding positive frequency bins if you want your IDFT output to be real. With matlab or octave, the correct way to do this truncation would be:

```
X = fft(x)
X(26:76) = 0;
result = ifft(X);
```

Note that this zeroes 51 coefficients - this number will have to be odd if you want to preserve symmetry (and thus keep the result real). Also, note that if you alter the other coefficients, you have to make sure that coefficients 100 to 77 are always the conjugate of coefficients 2:25 for the result to be real. For example :

```
X = fft(x)
X(26:76) = 0;
X(2:25) = X(2:25) + randn(24, 1) / 10;
X(77:100) = conj(flipud(X(2:25)));
result = ifft(X);
```

Comment: @pichnettes thanks for the info. But in the paper I mentioned, they wrote like they are retaining only the first d coefficients. I have also attached the screenshot of that paper. What do they mean by that? can u explain? I think I am taking things lightly. The paper doesn't seem to mention anything like that

Comment: In matlab, when you apply the 'fft' built-in function to a real vector of size N, you get a vector with $(X_0, X_1, X_2, X_3, ..., X_{N/2 - 1}, X_{N/2}, X_{N/2 - 1}^*, ..., X_2^*, X_1^*)$ where * denotes the complex conjugate. Thus, the first $d$ coefficients are located both at the beginning of the vector, and at the end of the vector in conjugate form; and the coefficients to eliminate are in the middle of the vector. You have to preserve this symmetry.

Comment: Thanks but i didn't get what you did in the code u posted above. You set X(26:76) = 0. Then why do you add randn(24,1)/10 and that also from X(2:25) not X(1:25) and what does flipud(X(2:25)) do? I would really appreciate if you could help.

Comment: The second part of my answer (with 'randn(24, 1)/10') is to illustrate that whenever you alter the coefficients, you have to make sure that the conjugate symmetry of the vector is maintained. I added some random noise as an example of transformation of the coefficients, and the code shows that whenever the coefficients are modified, the symmetry must be ensured by making sure that the "negative frequencies" coefficients are the conjugate of the "positive frequencies" coefficients.

Comment: If you read my comment above in which I give the layout of the output of matlab's 'fft' function, you'll see that the second coefficient is the conjugate of the last coefficient, the third coefficient is the conjugate of the penultimate coefficient and so on... The first coefficient is present once. flipud reverses its argument.